# how can set a timeout to a ObexListener object?

Tags: c#

I have a problem with the obexListener object, when executing the line:

ObexListenerContext context = obexListener.GetContext ();

That is waiting for the file that is sent by bluetooth and the program does not respond until it receives the file. But what happens if no file is sent? then it waits indefinitely and I have no way to stop the program.

How can I implement a waiting time and if nothing is received after that time, then the operation is canceled?
I leave the code: Thanks.

This is the full code:

```
private void codigo(object sender, BluetoothWin32AuthenticationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!obexListener.Authenticate)
            {
                switch (MessageBox.Show("Desea vincular el dispositivo: " + e.Device.DeviceName.ToString(), "Atención", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
                //switch (MessageBox.Show("PIN CODE" + e.NumberOrPasskeyAsString, "EMPAREJAMINETO", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
                {
                    case DialogResult.Yes:
                        e.Confirm = true;
                        break;
                    case DialogResult.No:
                        e.Confirm = false;
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                switch (MessageBox.Show("Desea vincular el dispositivo: " + e.Device.DeviceName.ToString(), "Atención", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
                //switch (MessageBox.Show("PIN CODE" + e.NumberOrPasskeyAsString, "EMPAREJAMINETO", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
                {
                    case DialogResult.Yes:
                        e.Confirm = true;
                        MessageBox.Show("Bienvenido Nuevamente!");
                        break;
                    case DialogResult.No:
                        e.Confirm = false;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

On load form:

```
ObexListener obexListener = new ObexListener(ObexTransport.Bluetooth);
            BluetoothWin32Authentication bluetoothWin32 = new BluetoothWin32Authentication(codigo);
            Guid guid = new Guid(BluetoothService.SerialPort.ToString());
            obexListener.Start();

            if (obexListener.IsListening)
            {
                timer2.Start();
                ObexListenerContext context = obexListener.GetContext();
                context.Request.WriteFile(archivoBluetooth);
                obexListener.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is two extension methods for `ObexListener`, that add timeout to `GetContext()`:

```
public static class ObexListenerExtensions
{
    public static ObexListenerContext GetContext(this ObexListener listener, int timeout)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(async () => await listener.GetContextAsync(timeout));
        return task.Result;
    }

    public static async Task<ObexListenerContext> GetContextAsync(this ObexListener obexListener, int timeout)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() => obexListener.GetContext());

        if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout)) == task)
        {
            return task.Result;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new TimeoutException();
        }
    }
}
```

Try to add it to your code as non-nested class and after that just replace:

```
ObexListenerContext context = obexListener.GetContext();
```

with:

```
ObexListenerContext context = obexListener.GetContext(1000);
```

Here timeput is in milliseconds. Hope it helps.

Comment: thaks kozhevnikov

Comment: hi koz, the code work thanks, but when the time is out send a error in the return  "return task.Result;" from the first method "GetContext". the exception says "TimeoutException: Se excedió el tiempo de espera de la operación.
" and then the program crash.

Comment: It is expected behavior. You see, when timeout has expired, method `GetContextAsync()` throws `TimeoutException`. In this case when code tries to access to `task.Result` in `GetContext`, the exception will be generated again in this particular line. You can change the implementation of `GetContextAsync()` like you want. For example return `null` when timeout has expired and then check result for null. I added `TimeoutException` just to illustrate the idea.